# Strange Timezone issue with Tapku Library Calendar

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-sdk-3.0, calendar, tapku

I have a weird problem with the Tapku Library Calendar.

I am showing events in Tapku Library Calendar. I am getting date from my server in America/Toronto Time zone. ie. -500.

My system  and calendar time zone set to Toronto,Canada in Setting app.

So, the problem is when Calendar show one event in wrong day view (day tiles). Event is on 16th November 2011 and it is showing on 17th on to the Calendar.

```
11/16/2011 17:00 -0500
```

So I found solution to make time zone as GMT.

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
```

And above working fine with Toronto time zone. Now, I set my timezone to Rome,Italy and It suppose to show that event on 16th too but it is showing on 17th.

so, the problem is if I keep above line it works fine with the Toronto, Canada Timezone and problem with the Rome,Italy Timezone and If I remove this line then it works fine for Rome,Italy and problem with Toronto,Italy.

For this I tried to set systemTimeZone and localTimeZone as well but still no luck.

So, what should I do to keep event on correct day view for all the timezones ?

Please let me know if you require any further details.

Comment: hi Deeps,me also facing the same problem.Can u tell me the solution if you got?

Comment: I am sorry I did not get answer yet. Problem is still there..

Comment: Can you post the full code showing how you parse the date string and convert it to a date?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer to a similar problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9405625/220154

I think the tapku calendar sets GMT:0 as the date it uses to compare against your dates, so it mess a lot with timezones. probably you would need to reduct the date to GMT midnight when you are checking what dates to include in the calendar.

hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

All [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]; should be replaced with [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

When it is not systemTimeZone you have to edit your dates coming out of the UIDatePicker to reflect time zone hour change, and all dates would be displayed a day later if you don't.

Here is the issue : https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary/issues/40

Comment: Thanks for this answer...replaced all and worked like a charm!