# How to check NSDate against a date in TAPKU calendar

Tags: ios, calendar, nsdate, tapku

I am using core data to store objects for my project.There is a date field in the object .I want to check against the clicked date of the Tapku calendar component for iphone. The date on my object is in the format

2011-01-10 and it is a localized date .

How can i check the date against the date returned from the tapku calendar control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, here is what I did to make it work:

on the method: (NSArray*)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView marksFromDate:(NSDate *)startDate toDate:(NSDate *)lastDate

- Make the normal core data fetch to get an array of objects
- Start checking every day from startDate to lastDate with the [NSArray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:] method
- For all that passes the test add and object to the marks array and add a dictionary with the tested day as key and the fetched objects as values

WARNING: make sure you cast your NSDate objects to a no time and GMT:0 dates in order to make the day comparison to work (learned this the hard way...)

Here is some code...

```
self.marksArray = [NSMutableArray array];
self.dataDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
[cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

NSDateComponents *comp = [cal components:(NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:start];

NSDate *ds = [cal dateFromComponents:comp];

// Init offset components to increment days in the loop by one each time
NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[offsetComponents setDay:1];


while (YES) {
    // Is the date beyond the last date? If so, exit the loop.
    // NSOrderedDescending = the left value is greater than the right
    if ([ds compare:end] == NSOrderedDescending) {
        break;
    }

    NSIndexSet *indexes = [arrayWithObjectsFromCoreData indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:
                           ^BOOL (id el, NSUInteger i, BOOL *stop) {
                               NSDate *upd = [(YOUR_ENTINY *)el updated];

                               NSDate *day=[self midnightUTC:upd]; 
                               if([ds isSameDay:day]){ 
                                   return TRUE;
                               }
                               return FALSE;
                           }];



    if (indexes.count>0) {

        [self.marksArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
        [self.dataDictionary setObject:[wods objectsAtIndexes:indexes] forKey:ds];


    }else {
        //no wods in this date
        [self.dataArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
    } 

    // Increment day using offset components (ie, 1 day in this instance)
    ds = [cal dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:ds options:0];



}
[offsetComponents release];
```

The midnightUTC method can be found here:
http://www.voidasterisk.org/post/4209842795/how-to-calculate-nsdate-of-midnight-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

Could do with a bit more information but the tapku library has an extension method on NSDate called isSameDay so you could use that:

```
if ([myDate isSameDay:returnedDate])
    // Do something here
```

Is that what you are looking for?